# How to add assignment @{} statements in Razor Pages inside loop

Tags: razor-pages

For instance, I want to perform the following

```
@foreach (var item in new List<int>() {0,1,2}) {
   @{
      var assignedItem = item + 1;
   }
   <div>@item</div>
   <div>@assignedItem</div>
}
```

But I get the error:

> Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

How would I add an assignment or other code within the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, you can write normal code in addition to HTML in the code statements.

```
@foreach (var item in new List<int>() {0,1,2}) {
   var assignedItem = item + 1;

   <div>@item</div>
   <div>@assignedItem</div>
}
```